# Access jquery-ui plugin variables from function inside plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a tagging plugin which I am re-factoring.

I keep passing around an object that I construct each time, So, instead I now have a function that I pass the values and it returns the object. This works fine, except now I need access to one of the variables in the plugin.

If you look at the bottom you will see inside `_addTag` I make a call to `this.tag` and I want to store the number of elements in the `tagArray` but my call to `this` doesn't call the widget.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.tagit", {

        // default options
        options:{},

        //initialization function
        _create:function () {

            var self = this;
            this.tagsArray = [];
            ...

            ...
            this._addTag('label', 'value');

            }

        },


        _addTag:function (label, value) {
            ...

            //THIS IS WHERE THE TAG OBJECT IS CREATED
            var tag = new this.tag(label, (value === undefined ? label : value));
            tag.element = $('<li class="tagit-choice"'
                + (value !== undefined ? ' tagValue="' + value + '"' : '')
                + '>' + label + '<a class="tagit-close">x</a></li>');
            ...
        },

        tag: function (label, value, element) {
            var self = this;
            return {
                label:label,
                value:value,
                element:element,
                index: self.tagsArray.length
            }
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

the call to `this` is instead:

```
$.widget.tag
__proto__: Object
constructor: function (label, value, element) {
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Ok, found my issue, it was the use of the `new` keyword. so my next question is. What difference is the `new` keyword making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `new` keyword in JavaScript to invoke a function invokes it with its context (`this`) set to a newly created object.

In your example within the `tag` function you're expecting `this` to be set to the widget object you're working with, but instead it will be set to the newly created object because of the use of the `new` keyword.  Therefore, it will fail on `self.tagsArray.length` because the newly created object doesn't have a `tagsArray` property.

For more information on the `new` keyword` I recommend reading the MDN article on it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.